# How do i change template_directory_uri?

Tags: wordpress

I've tried to install a local version of an existing wordpress site but I can't seem to get the local URL to be used on things like links. It also won't let me log in to the admin backend on my local install, everytime I try it redirects me to the login on the remote version.

I think I need to change `template_directory_uri` as there are places where that's called which is generating the remote site URL, like the CSS file for example. How do I change this to react to the local install?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress should work on XAMPP, determining the template_directory_uri automatically. Please provide more information about your setup so that we can properly help you.

The answer could be in the direction of functions.php or theme.php, as you can see:
http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/template_directory_uri

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - Somehow the site directory is being set in the database, so I used [this search & replace tool](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) to replace my remote URL with localhost.